# Generate PDF With LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, pdf, lightning-datatable, js, blob.topdf

Need to save a pdf of the particular div which include Lightning-Datatable.

Below are options I don't want to use as workaround:

1. window.print();
2. Vf redirect(Solutions without Visualforce Page)

Tried it but not working :

1. Converted the Lightning datatable in  table format in js and send the value in apex controller and tried to save it in Attachment with Blob.toPdf(). PDF is generating but not in the border and alignment.
2. I referred to this link as well: [Generating pdf - LWC - using jsPDF](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346650/generating-pdf-lwc-using-jspdf)
   I debugged it when it comes to const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf; it get break and didn't go further.

Is there any possible way to directly generate LWC particular div as it is in PDF?